# Typed React Function Component Template using Velocity Template Language

Tags: java, reactjs, webstorm, vtl

I am using Webstorm as my IDE. It allows me to highlight some JSX and extract a component as a function component. The code powering this feature is in VTL which I am not familiar with. When I extract a component such as this:

```
<button color="primary" onClick={reset} onBlur={handleBlur}>
  Cancel
</button>
```

VTL should create a function component with this signature:

```
interface NewComponentProps {
  onClick: () => void;
  onBlur: () => void;
}   
 
const NewComponent: React.FC<NewComponentProps> = ({ onClick, onBlur }) => {
      return (
        <button color="primary" onClick={onClick} onBlur={onBlur}>
          Cancel
        </button>
      );
    };
```

However, the VTL I have written is returning a function component with a signature of:

```
interface NewComponentProps {
  onClick: () => void;
  onBlur: () => void;
}

 const NewComponent: React.FC<NewComponentProps> = ({ onClick }) => {
      return (
        <button color="primary" onClick={onClick} onBlur={onBlur}>
          Cancel
        </button>
      );
    };
```

Which is not quite right. Notice the destructuring of the props only shows the first prop, and not the rest.

Here is the VTL template I wrote that is wrong:

```
    #if($PROP_TYPES)
interface ${NAME}Props 
    $PROP_TYPES
#end

#if($PROP_TYPES) #set($prop = $PROP_TYPES.substring(0, $PROP_TYPES.indexOf(":")).concat("}"))#end

#set( $BODY_NO_PROPS = $COMPONENT_BODY.replace("props.", "") )

const $NAME: React.FC#if($PROP_TYPES)<${NAME}Props>#end = (#if($PROP_TYPES) $prop#end) => {
  return $BODY_NO_PROPS
}

#if($DEFAULT_PROPS)
  $!{NAME}.defaultProps = $DEFAULT_PROPS
#end
```

I believe my issue stems from this line of VTL `#if($PROP_TYPES) #set($prop = $PROP_TYPES.substring(0, $PROP_TYPES.indexOf(":")).concat("}"))#end`

### I think the data structure is a map, and my code is not looping through the map to get all the keys of the map to display all the props.

```
Predefined variables will take the following values:
${NAME} - component name

${COMPONENT_BODY} - component body

${PROP_TYPES} - props type definition
```

How can I rewrite this template to take the form I want it too?

Answer (score 1):

Velocity supports Java [String](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) methods, you can try using them to parse the `$PROP_TYPES` and `$COMPONENT_BODY` strings accordingly. You can use regexp, for example (`$PROP_TYPES.replaceAll($regex, $replacement)`)

Possible solution:

```
#if($PROP_TYPES)
#set($NEWPROPS = $PROP_TYPES.replaceAll(":(.*?)(,|})", ",").concat("}"))
interface ${NAME}Props 
    $PROP_TYPES
#end
#set( $BODY_NO_PROPS = $COMPONENT_BODY.replace("props.", "") )

const $NAME: React.FC#if($PROP_TYPES)<${NAME}Props>#end = (#if($PROP_TYPES) $NEWPROPS#end) => {
  return $BODY_NO_PROPS
}

#if($DEFAULT_PROPS)
  $!{NAME}.defaultProps = $DEFAULT_PROPS
#end
```

Comment: Hey lena, I just tested this and it is a step in the right direction. However, if $PROP_TYPES has more than one item, this only prints the first item. I believe this structure is a map. Is there a way to print multiple items in the prop variable?

Comment: Velocity supports java [String](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) methods, you can try using them to parse the `$PROP_TYPES` string accordingly. You can use regexp, for example (`$PROP_TYPES.replaceAll($regex, $replacement)`)

Comment: On the $COMPONENT_BODY I was successfully able to use #set( $BODY_NO_PROPS = $COMPONENT_BODY.replace("props.", "") ) to remove the "props." The only issue is the $props only prints the first prop instead of prop, prop2, prop3, etc... and ideas on how to print them all? If the structure is like {'onClick': '() => ', 'prop2': 'true'} it should print { onClick, prop2 }

Comment: any idea on an answer for this after my last comment, and code edit? @Iena

Comment: see my updated answer above; not the best solution may be, I'm not good at regexp

Comment: any updates? does it work for you?

Comment: It works for about 80% of use cases but fails on types that have an object with a comma at the end. https://regex101.com/r/O5lx8D/2

Comment: Any update on this Iena?

Comment: what does your initial component (the one you extract a new component from) definition look like? It seems that the `$PROP_TYPES` format that I get is different from the one your are playing with