# Saving only keys of map to variable to display

Tags: webstorm, velocity, vtl

I am using WebStorm as my IDE. It allows you to use VTL to create templates that you can use to quickly build React components.

I am writing one that created a quick arrow function component. I am almost done, but I am stuck on one part.

WebStorm exposes a variable called `$PROP_TYPES`. It takes the form of something like this:

```
{"onClick": "() =>", "isActive": "true", "editing": "false"}
```

With these being all the props that are passed in to a component.

I need a way to loop through these and get the keys only and save them in this format:

```
{onClick, isActive, editing}
```

As these will be the props for the component. The problem is my code is only printing off the first prop and that is it.

Here is my VTL code:

```
#if($PROP_TYPES) #set($prop = $PROP_TYPES.substring(0, $PROP_TYPES.indexOf(":")).concat("}"))#end
```

My `$prop` variable is displaying the wrong thing.

Comment: It's not clear in your question whether `$PROP_TYPES` is a string or a map. The content you show would be a map, but your code treats it as a string. Does it mean that it contains the string representation of a map?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73821561/typed-react-function-component-template-using-velocity-template-language