# Remove values from Java map and replace with comma using Regex

Tags: java, regex, vtl

I have a regular expression that will target everything to the right of ":" in a map and to the left of a ","

I am using this RegExp:

```
:(.*?)(,|})
```

Like this:

```
$PROP_TYPES.replaceAll(":(.*?)(,|})", ",").concat("}")
```

This works well for the most part, except when the expression runs into objects that are on the right side of the ":"

For example, on a list of prop type definitions in TypeScript:

```
  "open": "boolean",
  "onDidDismiss": "() => void",
  "message": "string",
  "showAddReceiptModal": "boolean",
  "showModal": "(value: (((prevState: boolean) => boolean) | boolean)) => void",
  "vehicleTabRef": "React.MutableRefObject<null>",
  "onReceiptSubmit": "(data) => void",
  "vehicle": "any",
  "showModal1": "boolean",
  "showModal2": "(value: (((prevState: boolean) => boolean) | boolean)) => void",
  "selectedReceipt": "{ __typename: "Receipt" | undefined; id: string | undefined; purchaseDate: string | undefined; sellerName: string | undefined; sellerAddress: string | undefined; sellerCity: string | undefined; sellerState: string | undefined; sellerZipCode: string | undefined; totalAmount: number | undefined; gallonsPurchased: number | undefined; image?: string | null | undefined | undefined; userID?: string | null | undefined | undefined; vehicleID: string | undefined; vehicle?: Vehicle | null | undefined | undefined; taxRefund?: number | null | undefined | undefined; createdAt: string | undefined; updatedAt: string | undefined }",
  "onClick": "() => void",
  "onClick1": "() => void",
  "dataEditing": "boolean",
  "toastMessage": "(val) => void",
  "editing": "(bool) => void",
  "showToast": "(bool) => void",
  "showModal3": "boolean",
  "showModal4": "(bool) => void",
  "dateFilter": "{ startDate: string; endDate: string }",
```

When I run replaceAll with this regex, and the replacement is a comma I am left with this:

```
  open,
  onDidDismiss,
  message,
  showAddReceiptModal,
  showModal,
  vehicleTabRef,
  onReceiptSubmit,
  vehicle,
  showModal1,
  showModal2,
  selectedReceipt,                                                 
  , 
  onClick, 
  onClick1, 
  dataEditing,
  toastMessage, 
  editing, 
  showToast, 
  showModal3, 
  showModal4, 
  dateFilter, 
  ,
```

Notice the empty commas, these should not be here. This expression should target everything to the right of the ":" and replace it all with a comma.

This code is written in VTL to use with the Webstorm IDE to create quick typescript templates. But Java string manipulation works as well

What regex can I use to only remove everything to the right of the `:` to the ending comma, and just leave that comma?

Answer (score 0):

You might use:

```
^\s*\"([^\"]+)\":.*(?=,)
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `\s*` Match optional whitespace chars (Or use `\h*` in Java to not match newlines)
- `\"([^\"]+)\"` Capture in group 1 all between double quotes
- `:.*` Match `:` and then the rest of the line
- `(?=,)` Positive lookahead, assert a comma to the right

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/krT8qP/1)

In the replacement use capture group 1.

The result after the replacement:

```
open,
onDidDismiss,
message,
showAddReceiptModal,
showModal,
vehicleTabRef,
onReceiptSubmit,
vehicle,
showModal1,
showModal2,
selectedReceipt,
onClick,
onClick1,
dataEditing,
toastMessage,
editing,
showToast,
showModal3,
showModal4,
dateFilter,
```

Comment: Unfortunately my webstorm IDE is saying "Error parsing file template: Lexical error, Encountered: "(" (40), after : "" at *unset*[line 6, column 65]" when I use this regex in the replace all. Not sure what it doesn't like about it.

Comment: @klaurtar1 So you are using the replace functionality in webstorm, and then in the search bar you paste this regex (and enable regex pressing the button with  `.*`). Then in the replacement you put `$1` ?

Comment: @klaurtar1 If I do the same in my Intellij I do not get an error, and I see the right replacements.

Comment: I am on WebStorm. If you go too: Preferences > File and Code Templates > Typed React Function Component. You can write VTL that when you highlight some JSX you can extract it to a new component, using the VTL you placed. I'm using your regex in my replace all function and it errors out. I think it is because it matches the keys as well. The regex I posted works 80% of the time, but I noticed it doesn't select the ending " in some situations.

Comment: @klaurtar1 Try writing it like this `$PROP_TYPES.replaceAll(/^\s*\"([^\"]+)\":.*(?=,)/g, "$1");` or `$PROP_TYPES.replaceAll(/^\s*"([^"]+)":.*(?=,)/g, "$1");`

Comment: Tried them both and they both error out :-( Seems like I can't get it to work

Comment: @klaurtar1 what is the error?

Comment: On the first one I get

Error parsing file template: Lexical error, Encountered: "/" (47), after : "" at *unset*[line 6, column 58]

On the second one I get:

Error parsing file template: Lexical error, Encountered: "/" (47), after : "" at *unset*[line 6, column 58]

If you want to see my implementation (and possibly get my bounty) you can check out my post here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73821561/typed-react-function-component-template-using-velocity-template-language

Comment: We're you able to check it out?

Comment: @klaurtar1 I tried to check that, but unfortunately I don't have the `Preferences > File and Code Templates > Typed React Function Component` What if you try it with the RegExp constructor? `$PROP_TYPES.replaceAll(new RegExp("^\\s*\"([^\"]+)\":.*(?=,)", "g"), "$1");`